# SQL - are my pictures saving to database correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

are my pictures saving to database correctly, because i can't load them back.

[image: take a look at this image]

in the image very few bytes seems to save, to i suppose they are not saving correctly because i'm not able to recive them back :(

```
    public byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

i used this to convert image to bytes, then i saved it in the db

```
        SqlConnection MyCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-3DH5S38\\HR_SERVER;Initial Catalog=BMS_PRO_DB;Integrated Security=True");

    private void CreateAccount_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCon.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Bank_Accounts_Information (CustomerName,AccountNo,AccountTitle,AccountType,Gender,DOB,Nationality,PostalAddress,PhoneNumber,NicNumber,EmailAddress,CompanyName,Occupation,AccountBalance,ProfilePic,SignaturePic) VALUES('" + CustomerName_textBox.Text+"' , '"+AccountNumber_textBox.Text+"' , '"+AccountTitle_textbox .Text+"' , '"+AccountType_ComboBox.Text + "' , '" + WhichGender + "' , '" + MyDateTimePicker.Text + "' , '" +Nationality_ComboBox.Text + "' , '" +PostalAddress_textbox.Text + "' , '" + (PhoneNo_ComboBox.Text+PhoneNo_textBox.Text) + "' , '" + NicNumber_textbox.Text+ "' , '" +(EmailAddress_textbox.Text+EmailAddress_atComboBox.Text) + "' , '" +CompanyName_textbox.Text + "' , '" +Occupation_textbox.Text + "' , '" +InitialDeposit_textbox.Text +"' , '"+ Pb_SetObj.ImageToByte(Profile_Picture_PictureBox.Image) + "', '" + Pb_SetObj.ImageToByte(Signature_PictureBox.Image) + "')";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, MyCon);
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyCon.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Account Successfully Created");
    }
```

Comment: Who knows? Can you share some code? As posted this is not answerable.

Comment: yes, share some code, it is also good to save the picture files on filesystem and save their path only in DB

Comment: What do you mean you cannot load them back?  Code? Error Message?

Comment: Please use parameters in you query, not string concatenation. This a) prevents you from Sql Injection and b) can solve your issue ([see here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/how-to-save-the-image-into-the-database/) )

Comment: please answer now!

Comment: The way you have done it, is not a good way. Better follow [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25956/Sending-Receiving-PictureBox-Image-in-C-To-From-Mi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the image is not being saved correctly. It seems you are storing the string value of the type name instead of the byte array as the query below shows.

Post your problem code if you need help storing the binary value.

```
SELECT CAST(0X53797374656D2E427974655B5D AS varchar(10));
```

Result:

```
System.Byte[]
```

**EDIT:**

Below is a parameterized query example. I took guesses at your databases types and lengths. You should change the parameter types and max length specification to match your actual table schema and set the values using stringly-typed values too (e.g. `DateTime` instead of `String`).

There is no value in using a SqlDataAdapter like your original code, and I find it confusing using the `SelectCommand` for an insert.

Note that this assumes your `Pb_SetObj` method must return the byte array of the image;

```
using (var MyCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
{
    MyCon.Open();

    string query =
        @"INSERT INTO tbl_Bank_Accounts_Information (CustomerName,AccountNo,AccountTitle,AccountType,Gender,DOB,Nationality,PostalAddress,PhoneNumber,NicNumber,EmailAddress,CompanyName,Occupation,AccountBalance,ProfilePic,SignaturePic)
    VALUES(@CustomerName,@AccountNo,@AccountTitle,@AccountType,@Gender,@DOB,@Nationality,@PostalAddress,@PhoneNumber,@NicNumber,@EmailAddress,@CompanyName,@Occupation,@AccountBalance,@ProfilePic,@SignaturePic);";

    var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, MyCon);

    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = CustomerName_textBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = AccountNumber_textBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = AccountTitle_textbox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = AccountType_ComboBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = WhichGender;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = MyDateTimePicker.Value;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Nationality_ComboBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@PostalAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = PostalAddress_textbox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = PhoneNo_ComboBox.Text + PhoneNo_textBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@NicNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = NicNumber_textbox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = EmailAddress_textbox.Text + EmailAddress_atComboBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = CompanyName_textbox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Occupation ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Occupation_textbox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountBalance", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = InitialDeposit_textbox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProfilePic", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = Pb_SetObj.ImageToByte(Profile_Picture_PictureBox.Image);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SignaturePic", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = Pb_SetObj.ImageToByte(Signature_PictureBox.Image);

    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MyCon.Close();

}
```

Comment: please look at the code and tell me what i'm doing i'm quite a beginner at handling database problems.

Comment: @HassaanRaza, you should [always use parameterized queries](http://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) for security, performance, and other reasons. I'll add a code example to my answer.

Comment: Your current method just uses string concatenation. You should look into something like Entity Framework

Comment: thanks so much i will correct the types and adjust the code, i will also try to write the code myself and reference your code if i went wrong somewhere, happy coding :)

Comment: another thing is that i saw this in another place too, that for storing images , varbinary (MAX) was used, but i had used the image type.

Comment: @HassaanRaza, SQL type `image` will work but it's been deprecated since SQL 2005. Better to `se 'varbinary(MAX)` for new development.

Answer (score 0):

i tried so hard and finally i succeeded!

```
 SqlConnection MyCon = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-3DH5S38123\\HR2_SERVER;database=BMS_PRO_DB;Integrated Security =true");
            string query = @"INSERT INTO tbl_Bank_Accounts_Information (CustomerName,AccountNo,AccountTitle,AccountType,Gender,DOB,Nationality,PostalAddress,PhoneNumber,NicNumber,EmailAddress,CompanyName,Occupation,AccountBalance,ProfilePic,SignaturePic) VALUES(@CustomerName,@AccountNo,@AccountTitle,@AccountType,@Gender,@DOB,@Nationality,@PostalAddress,@PhoneNumber,@NicNumber,@EmailAddress,@CompanyName,@Occupation,@AccountBalance,@ProfilePic,@SignaturePic);";
            SqlCommand comnd = new SqlCommand(query, MyCon);
            MyCon.Open();
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", CustomerName_textBox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", AccountNumber_textBox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountTitle", AccountTitle_textbox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountType", AccountType_ComboBox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", WhichGender);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", MyDateTimePicker.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", Nationality_ComboBox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalAddress", PostalAddress_textbox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", (PhoneNo_ComboBox.Text + PhoneNo_textBox.Text));
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NicNumber", NicNumber_textbox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", (EmailAddress_textbox.Text + EmailAddress_atComboBox.Text));
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", CompanyName_textbox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", Occupation_textbox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountBalance", InitialDeposit_textbox.Text);
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfilePic", Pb_SetObj.ImageToByte(Profile_Picture_PictureBox.Image));
            comnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignaturePic", Pb_SetObj.ImageToByte(Signature_PictureBox.Image));
            comnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyCon.Close();
```

Dan guzman's solution literally gave me a page full of error but i choose his answer as best because my question was "are my pictures saving to database correctly" and he answered it honestly.

Comment: Although AddWithValue will work, it has some [major negative downsides](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).